# math.cos(t) and an array for t results in an error. how to solve this?

Tags: python, arrays, trigonometry

so this is the code:

```
def s(t):
    return math.cos(2*(math.pi)*10*t)
s1_n = s(n1T)
```

error message: "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

this is the output for

```
n1T
```

"array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ,
0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21,
0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32,
0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43,
0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5 , 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54,
0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65,
0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76,
0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 , 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87,
0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98,
0.99, 1.  ])"

this are the used modules:

> from thkdsp import * from dsplab import * from numpy import arange,
> shape, array, zeros, size, ones, isscalar %pylab inline from
> thkdsp.interpolation import ideal_interpolation from
> thkdsp.interpolation import ideal_interpolation_mat

how to solve this?
-thanks!!

Comment: Use `np.cos`? The `math` module is not supposed to work with numpy arrays. `math` is a Python built-in, `numpy` is a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself :)

Just use `numpy.cos(...)` and it works perfectly.